# Attribute is not rendered in json answer

Tags: ruby-on-rails, serialization

I'm changing existing serializer in ruby on rails(4.2) project adding new custom attribute to serializer(test123), which is not in model. But this attribute is not rendered in json answer which is formed via this serializer. Also i can change values of existing attributes (like author_name), which is in model.
Model contains of id and author_name.
Json is formed in controller of a class which has_many Examples.

My serializer:

```
class ExampleSerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer
  attributes :id,
             :author_name,
             :test123

  def test123
    Rails.logger.debug("???!!!")
    "test"
  end
  def author_name
    "test"
  end
end
```

Part of my controller:

```
def show
  render  json: @system,
          include: %w[examples and other included data],
          adapter: :json_api_secured,
          each_serializer: detect_serializer
end
```

Server calls test123 (i see it by print ???!!! in logs), but in formed answer there is no field test123.
What can be a problem?

Comment: Have you provided actual sources? At least comma is missed after `attributes :id`.

Comment: it is mistype, there is comma in source